# D3 lines aren't plotting but the axis and legend are rendered, still getting path is not a num error despite date formatting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to build a multi-line chart with d3 in react and no matter what I do I can't get any lines to show up. I've tried to make a single line chart as well with completely different much simpler data, still same issue, but I don't know what I'm missing.

I've looked through all the d3 questions on stack overflow and none of the answers worked for my problem.

I've tried formatting the date in different ways because I am also getting an `Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number` error

I've tried simplifying my data. I've tried manually hardcoding very simple data that is just straight numbers and trying to graph that just to test. Still no line.

I've ended up just using canvasjs or victory charts but I really want to learn to make this work.

Here is my data:

```
dataSeries = [

{date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 99, mood: "happy"},
{date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 68, mood: "active"},
 {date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 42, mood: "happy"},
{date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 72, mood: "active"},
{date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 5, mood: "tired"},
{date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 55, mood: "anxious"},
 {date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 34, mood: "angry"},
{date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 23, mood: "sad"},
{date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 96, mood: "active"},
 {date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 95, mood: "active"},
 {date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 13, mood: "sad"},
 {date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 16, mood: "tired"},
 {date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 45, mood: "fine"},
 {date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 23, mood: "anxious"},
{date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 75, mood: "anxious"},
 {date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 19, mood: "angry"},
 {date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 7, mood: "angry"},
 {date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 55, mood: "fine"},
 {date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 6, mood: "happy"},
 {date: "Thu Apr 25 2019", level: 94, mood: "active"},
 {date: "Fri Apr 26 2019", level: 82, mood: "happy"},
 {date: "Fri Apr 26 2019", level: 96, mood: "happy"},
 {date: "Fri Apr 26 2019", level: 96, mood: "happy"},
 {date: "Fri Apr 26 2019", level: 65, mood: "anxious"}

];
```

dates before re-formatting look like this:

`Thu Apr 25 2019 17:16:26 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

but they are originally like this `2019-04-26T19:51:11.622Z`
but I run new Date(Date.parse()) on them before they go into the data set

Here is my d3 chart code:

```
var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50},
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var formatDate = d3.timeFormat('%a %b %d %Y');

    let dataPoints = dataSet.map(function(d) {
            return {
                date: formatDate(d.date),
                level: +d.level,
                mood: d.mood
            };
    });

    console.log(dataPoints); 

    const maxDate = moment()
    const minDate = moment().subtract(2, 'week');

    let xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);
    let yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

    let line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date)})
        .y(function (d) { return yScale(d.level)})
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)

    var svg = d3.select('#moodChart').append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    var dataNest = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.mood; }).entries(dataPoints) 

    let color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemePaired);

    let legendSpace = height / dataNest.length;

    dataNest.forEach(function(d, i){
        svg.append('path')
            .attr('class', 'line')
            .style('stroke', function() {
                return d.color = color(d.key);
            })
            .attr('d', line(d.values))

        svg.append('text')
            .attr('y', (legendSpace/5)+ i * legendSpace)
            .attr('x', width - (margin.right / 3))
            .attr('class', 'legend')
            .style('fill', function() {
                return d.color = color(d.key);
            })
            .text(d.key)
    });

    svg.append('g').attr('class', 'xAxis').attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(7));

    svg.append('g').attr('class', 'yAxis').call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
```

here is what the graph currently looks like:

[image: chart with only axis and legend showing]

[link for photo as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dQUe.jpg)

I would like each mood to have it's only line, with the date recorded on the x axis and the intensity level on the y axis.

But I can't get any lines to show up

Comment: You aren't formatting a date - you are parsing a date string, try d3.timeParse where d3.timeFormat appears.

Comment: I tried it, but there are still no lines and all the dates become null after the timeParse

Comment: Have you got a Fiddle or something, so we can fix this?

Comment: Here is the [GitHub branch](https://github.com/MxOliver/Pocket-Therabuddy/tree/graph-overlap) I'm trying to figure out how to put it on JSFiddle there is just a lot of dependencies and stuff

Comment: this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MxOliver/1hs79odk/28/) is pretty close to the relevant parts of the code, just without redux/react stuff. For some reason it's not rendering the legend though and on my version it is, but either way neither have lines

Comment: @MxOliver, your code worked for me with that change, using the question's code block and the example data, I'm pre-occupied at the moment, but will make a fiddle to demonstrate if needed later.

Comment: Maybe I'm setting up D3 or something else fundamental wrong. If you could post a fiddle when you get the chance that would be super helpful

Comment: I took out the date parsing and just did new Date(d.date) instead and then I put the d3.timeFormat as part of my axis tick format and it's working! Thanks @AndrewReid